# Errors when reading a lookup field of a list item using the JavaScript Object Model

Tags: javascript, jsom

I changed a field from being a single line of text, to being a lookup (still only displaying a single line of text, but it's fetched from another list. The field's internal name is `Status`. This is where I get an error:

```
oListItem.get_item('Status');
```

The error reads:

```
The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.
```

So I changed this line

```
clientContext.load(listItemCollection);
```

to

```
clientContext.load(listItemCollection, 'Include(Status)');
```

Now, the `executeQueryAsync`'s failure handler is called with the following error:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Any ideas what might be causing this? The code worked before I changed the column type, so the problem shouldn't be with any other code...

Edit:

Based on Dikesh Gandhi's suggestion, I tried adding the following to my caml query:

```
<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Status" /></ViewFields></View>
```

But then the original error (not initialized) returned, regardless of if I have the include-string passed to the `load` function.

Comment: try to access with oListItem.get_item('Status').get_lookupValue()

Comment: This makes no difference, still getting the same error.

Comment: Add  status in ViewFields in caml query.

Comment: I tried this (see my edit), but it resulted in the first error again.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there can be few causes as mentioned below.

1. Use of invalid field name. You need to use the internal field name!
2. Change the List View Lookup Threshold value of the web application. Default value is 8.

Comment: The internal name is correct. The List View Lookup Threshold is at 12, but what exactly does this value mean?

Comment: @aegarn this value determines how much lookup values are fetched (in case there are more than x lookup columns on a list item). i had the same problem recently and i had to raise the threshold from 16 to 22 until i finally got the field value because our users add tons of fields to lists, thereby making a bigger lookup threshold necessary for the js to work properly.

Comment: The list only has 2 lookup fields, so a threshold of 12 should be enough, right?

Comment: It is more than enough.

Comment: You need to put your source code so i can understand it & help you further on the same... :)

Answer (score 0):

Is that column is lookup and display type ?
please check column name in list seetings as columnName:title. If so need to change the column reference

Comment: The display name in list settings is "Current phase", but if I click it I can see the internal name in the status bar: `&Field=Status`

Comment: oListItem.get_item("Country").get_lookupValue(); In this country is the look up column for the list.

Comment: is that you have selected the checkbox below **"Add a column to show each of these additional fields:"** the dropdown , inorder to select the columns for look up . if so please remove that . and simply select the column only .

Comment: I did have one column checked in **Add a column to show each of these additional fields:**, but removing that made no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: How you have changed the single line colum to look up **as we get only  Single line of text
 Multiple lines of text
 Choice (menu to choose from)
 Number (1, 1.0, 100)
 Currency ($, ¥, €)
 Date and Time  , these options only.**

Comment: The field that the lookup points to is a "Single line of text" (it's the default Title field)

Answer (score 0):

Are you on 2010 or 2013?

`Status` is the internal fieldname of SharePoints default `Task Status` feld on 2013

So if you create a new Field `Status` it will be `Status0` (or was it 1 ?) for the Internal Name

Comment: 2013. It returns the same error for both `Status0` and `Status1` unfortunately. And if I put them in the `Include` string, I get `Column 'Status1' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.`

Comment: Go into the settings of the field and check the URL, it will use the internal fieldname in the URL

Comment: The url says `Field=Status`

Comment: Double check: Go check the internal name for the default (Task)Status field in the Site Column definitions or open a default Tasks List and check the field in the List Settings... [here](http://i.imgur.com/v9yOBJA.jpg) is my screenshot of a default Tasks List (on Office365) which shows the internal name as ''Status'' in the URL. You can not have identical internal names.

Comment: It's a `Custom list`, not a `Tasks` list, so that field isn't present.

Comment: [Screenshot of URL](http://i.imgur.com/94eg8nI.png)

Comment: I gave two options, use the first: Go check in Site Settings/Site Collection Columns what the internal name is for the original SharePoint Task Status field

Comment: [Original task status internal name](http://i.imgur.com/UWA756R.png) - it's "TaskStatus"